# Add Spring Boot static file serving path based upon active profile

Tags: spring-boot, static-files

I have a Spring Boot application using `spring-boot-starter-web`. How can I serve static content from a local directory *outside* the `src/` hierarchy, but only if a certain profile is active?

For example, let's say my application is served from `localhost:8080/app/`. I want to be able to serve static files from `./data/extra` (relative to my project—without using an absolute path) and have them available at `localhost:8080/extra/`, but only if the `extra` profile is active.

I imagine I could implement a separate controller and put the `@Profile("extra")` annotation on it, but I wonder if there is a simpler approach that involves only adding the path mapping in some configuration.